# Gamma matrices are irreducible

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, mp.mathematical-physics, clifford-algebras

For $\mu=0,1,2,3$, let $\gamma^{\mu}$ the set of Dirac gamma matrices. What does it mean to say that $\{\gamma^{\mu}: \hspace{0.1cm} \mu=0,1,2,3\}$ is irreducible?

From my [previous question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/386335/what-is-the-relationship-between-the-dirac-algebra-and-the-clifford-algebra), I know that the gamma matrices determine a representation $\rho$ of the Clifford algebra $\mathcal{C}l_{1,3}(\mathbb{R}^{4},\Phi)$ in the algebra of $4\times 4$ complex matrices. Many references state that the gamma matrices are irreducible representations of $\mathcal{C}l_{1,3}(\mathbb{R}^{4},\Phi)$, which means that for every $x \in \mathcal{C}l_{1,3}(\mathbb{R}^{4},\Phi)$, $\rho(x)$ has no non-trivial invariant subspaces.

However, as discussed [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/138335/dirac-group-representation), the gamma matrices can also determine a group $\Gamma_{\text{Dirac}}$ with elements $I, \pm \gamma^{\mu}, \pm \gamma^{\mu}\gamma^{\nu}$, $\mu = 0,1,2,3,5$ and $\mu < \nu$. Here $\gamma^{5} := \gamma^{0}\gamma^{1}\gamma^{2}\gamma^{3}$. And the notion of irreducible representation also holds for groups.

So, getting back from the original question, when one says $\{\gamma^{\mu}: \hspace{0.1cm} \mu=0,1,2,3\}$, what does it mean exactly? Maybe both notions defined above have some natural connection?

**ADD:** *I think* I got it. It can be shown that the representation $\rho : \mathcal{C}l_{1,3}(\mathbb{R}^{4},\Phi) \to M_{4\times 4}(\mathbb{C})$ is not only faithful, but also a bijection. Thus, because it is surjective, the representation is irreducible. Now, each element of the Dirac group $\Gamma_{\text{Dirac}}$ is, in particular, the image $\rho(x)$ of an element $x \in \mathcal{C}l_{1,3}(\mathbb{R}^{4},\Phi)$ under the representation $\rho$. Thus, there is no (non-trivial) subspace of $\mathbb{C}^{4}$ which is invariant under the action of any of these elements. Hence, the representation $\tilde{\rho}: \Gamma_{\text{Dirac}} \to M_{4\times 4}(\mathbb{C})$ given by $\tilde{\rho}(x) = x$ must be irreducible. In summary, because $\rho$ is irreducible, the group representation $\tilde{\rho}$ is irreducible.

Any comments and corrections are welcome.

**EDIT:** I actually don't know if the surjectivity of $\rho$ implies $\rho$ to be irreducible.

**ADD 2:** To clarify, the space $M_{4\times 4}(\mathbb{C})$ mentioned before is being considered as a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$, as well as $\mathcal{C}l_{1,3}(\mathbb{R}^{4},\Phi)$. Surely one can complexify $\mathcal{C}l_{1,3}(\mathbb{R}^{4},\Phi)$ to get a new Clifford algebra $\mathcal{C}l_{1,3}(\mathbb{R}^{4},\Phi)_{\mathbb{C}}$ which now is isomorphic to $M_{4\times 4}(\mathbb{C})$, the latter being considered as an algebra over $\mathbb{C}$.

After posting this question, some ideas and questions have arisen. Let me summarize the important points/questions below:

- It is not clear to me yet if the irreducibility of $\rho: \mathcal{C}l_{1,3}(\mathbb{R}^{4},\Phi)\to M_{4\times 4}(\mathbb{C})$ is equivalent to the irreducibility of $\tilde{\rho}: \Gamma_{\text{Dirac}} \to M_{4\times 4}(\mathbb{C})$ in any way. However, as I tried to prove above, the irreducibility of $\rho$ seems to imply the irreducibility of $\tilde{\rho}$.
- It is also not clear if the proof I give before is correct, that is, I don't know if the bijectivity of $\rho$ is enough to garantee that it is irreducible.
- In the physics literature, it is sometimes not clear if the matrix algebra is being considered as a *real* or *complex* algebra, so I don't if the representation from $\rho: \mathcal{C}l_{1,3}(\mathbb{R}^{4},\Phi) \to M_{4\times 4}(\mathbb{C})$ is irreducible *or* if we need to complexify $\mathcal{C}l_{1,3}(\mathbb{R}^{4},\Phi)$ to get a irreducible representation $\hat{\rho}: \mathcal{C}l_{1,3}(\mathbb{R}^{4},\Phi)_{\mathbb{C}}\to M_{4\times 4}(\mathbb{C})$. Some references suggest that the complex case is irreducible, and I wasn't able to find a proof of this fact or some indiciation if the real case is also irreducible.

Comment: These notions are equivalent. We can think of the Clifford algebra as the group algebra of the group generated by the gamma matrices. The definitions of "irreducible representation" is such that the versions on each side are equivalent.

Comment: Actually, I think my comment may be wrong: I was saying something about the relationship between a representation of a group and of its group algebra (which is *not* the same thing as the Lie algebra of a Lie group.) I think the spirit of what I said is true, but you might want to wait for someone with more experience translating between physics and math terminology.

Comment: @CalvinMcPhail-Snyder I added some new thoughts. Maybe this is a more natural way of thinking on the problem.

Comment: The term "irreducible" can be applied to any collection of matrices: it means that there are no non-trivial _jointly_ invariant subspaces for this collection. Of course, the property of being irreducible (or conversely reducible) does not distinguish between the collection and the matrix sub-algebra that it generates.

Comment: @IgorKhavkine this is very helpful. Is it easy to prove this irreducibility? I thought I knew how to prove but now I'm not sure.

Comment: @IamWill For the $\gamma$-matrices, I think that the proof via the isomorphism $\rho \colon \mathcal{C}l_{1,3}(\mathbb{R}^{4},\Phi) \to M_{4\times 4}(\mathbb{C})$ that you have already mentioned may be the conceptually clearest one.

Comment: @IgorKhavkine yes, I thought so but how does the isomorphism implies irreducibility? I was trying to use it on my edit but this is where I got confused. Just to clarify, when you write $\rho: \mathcal{C}l_{1,3}(\mathbb{R}^{4},\Phi) \to M_{4\times 4}(\mathbb{C})$ you are considering both algebras over $\mathbb{R}$ right?

Comment: @IamWill Sorry, I didn't pay enough attention to where you were using $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$ when I cut-and-pasted the formula. The notes about Clifford algebras by Trautman (posted to one of your previous questions) give a very clear treatment of all the cases. Over $\mathbb{C}$, the $\gamma$-matrices are reducible, where the joint invariant subspaces are the eigenspaces of $\gamma_5$. On each of these subspaces, they become the Pauli $\sigma$-matrices, which together with $I$ do generate $M_{2\times 2}(\mathbb{C})$, so there are no smaller invariant subspaces.

Comment: @IgorKhavkine it seems that the easiest way to prove the irreducibility of $\rho$ is to prove that the family of four matrices $\gamma^{\mu}$ is irreducible, no? These are only four matrices and if there is no jointly invariant subspace for them, there will be no jointy invariant subspace for $\rho(x)$, $x \in \mathcal{C}l_{1,3}(\mathbb{R}^{4},\Phi)$.

Comment: @IamWill I seem to have slipped up with the commutation properties of $\gamma_5$ (it anti-commutes with $\gamma_\mu$ in 4d; but the analogous commutation/anti-commutation properties alternate in higher dimensions). If you've spotted that, then you're likely capable of writing a complete answer to your own question, which is not a bad practice from time to time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The irreducible representations of the Clifford algebra $C$ and the associated group $\Gamma$ (Dirac group) are worked out in [these notes.](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9811101)

In *even* $D$ space-time dimensions (in particular, for $D=3+1=4$) the group $\Gamma$ has $2^D+1$ inequivalent irreducible representations. Of these $2^D$ are one-dimensional, and the remaining representation has dimension $2^{D/2}$. The Clifford algebra itself has only one irreducible representation and this has dimension $2^{D/2}$. This spinor representation is constructed in the cited notes (section 1.2). For $D=4$ with the signature $(-1,+1,+1,+1)$ these are the four Dirac matrices.

Comment: Thanks Carlo, this seems like a very useful reference!